# MySQL statement

Tags: mysql5.5

How to create a MySQL statement to check expiry and and deactivate a/c on matched date?

```
desc mailbox;
username varchar
pass     varchar
created  datetime
expiry   datetime
active   tinyint(1)
```

I need to expire a/c (username filed) on expiry date which should be `active=0`

Comment: This question is off-topic and would be better asked on StackOverflow (where you already have an account).

Comment: Perhaps on dba.se

Answer (score 1):

Did you think yourself about the problem before you asked here? The statement is pretty easy to do, just translate english to SQL:

Update my mailbox table and set active to 0 where expiry is less than now:

```
UPDATE mailbox SET active = 0 WHERE expiry < NOW()
```

Notice: It would be better to check `expiry < NOW()` every time you select something from the table because an entry could expire and be queried before the next run of your expiry-statement.

Comment: An even cleaner approach might be to use a view containing the necessary constraints (filtering for "active" and "expiry").